# org.json.JSONException: JSONArray[0] is not a JSONObject

Tags: java, json

Output of `String jsreturn: [{"type":1, "msg":"ERROR"}]`.

I'm trying to get the content of `msg` key which is ERROR. I'm doing that by transforming string return into an array. However I'm getting some errors commented next to each line on the follow code.
Any insight?

```
 Vector<ClsReturn> ret = null;
 ret = ds.id(collection, "fs",in_uri );

 String jsReturn = ret.toString();

 JSONObject myJsonObject = new JSONObject(ret);

 JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsReturn); 

 int i = 0;

 while(i < array.length()){
     myJsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i); //org.json.JSONException: JSONArray[0] is not a JSONObject.
     System.out.println(myJsonObject.getString("msg"));
     i++;
 }
```

Comment: Your example doesn't really make sense since you are trying to access `msg` which your JSON doesn't have (at least the one you are showing us).  Also your array represents `solrReturn`, not `jsReturn` which holds your JSON.

Comment: It's not how you should write JSon array, SOLr return type is not intended to be used with json objects, inorder to return array of json objects either define a list of object that contains those two parameters, or there is a list of wildcard.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem with your current code, which suggests that `jsReturn` may not contain JSON structure you are describing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont know if I have understood your question, I think it is easy, this works:

```
    String jsReturn =" [{\"type\":1, \"txt\":\"ERROR\"}]";
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsReturn); 
    int i = 0;
    JSONObject myJsonObject = new JSONObject();
    while(i < array.length()){
        myJsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i); 
        System.out.println(myJsonObject.getString("txt"));
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: At this point your answer suggests that OP code should work. Please read: [Are “works for me” answers valid?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118992/are-works-for-me-answers-valid)

Comment: Thanks @Pshermo I must consider this detail, however the question indicates ' I'm getting some errors commented' and this answer must solve the error. If the question consider important to understand why it occurs I will explain the code. Thanks again

Comment: But OP claims that error still appears despite now having example in question which is similar to solution from your answer. Main difference is that OP didn't ensure that `jsReturn` holds `[{\"type\":1, \"txt\":\"ERROR\"}]` like in your answer which suggests that real response is now what OP thinks. So your answer can be useful in sense that it points to possible cause of problem, but it current form it doesn't explain nor solve anything. I will not downvote it but IMO possible problem suggestion is better done via comment and answer should contain 100% sure/correct solutions.

Comment: Oh, and there is no `r` in my nick :) it is `@Pshemo` not `Pshermo`.